# Java: How to properly return result using a method

Tags: java, swing, parameters, return

I writing a program that will print "Based on the temperature it is likely" season A, B, C, or D by calling a method.

Code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Seasons {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int inputTemp;
    String response = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
            "Enter the temperature");
    inputTemp = Integer.parseInt(response);
    String message = "Based on the temperature of " + inputTemp
            + " it is most likely " + determineSeason(inputTemp);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);

  }

  public static String determineSeason(int inputTemp) {
    String season = null;
    if (inputTemp > 130 || inputTemp < -20) { 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid");
    }

    else if (inputTemp >= 90) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"summer"); }

    else if (inputTemp >= 70 && inputTemp < 90) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"spring"); }
    else { 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"winter"); }

    return season; 
  }
}
```

The program is returning with a JOptionPane the season from my method, then presents the JOptionPane from main method where I need it to say "Based on the temperature the season is Season A, B, C, or D.

Any advice on what I'm missing would be appreciated!

Comment: You are sowing the JOptionPane in the `determineSeason`, but not setting any value to `season`, and just return it, so it will be null.

Comment: @KevinO:  I'd say post an answer the next time you see a question like this, since you're correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`determineSeason` should be a private method that doesn't deal with UI parts (doesn't interact with Swing components).

```
private String determineSeason(int inputTemp) {
    if (inputTemp > 130 || inputTemp < -20) { 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid");
    }

    if (inputTemp >= 90) {
        return "summer";
    } else if (inputTemp >= 70 && inputTemp < 90) {
        return "spring";
    } else { 
        return "winter";
    }
}
```

`season` can't be `"Invalid"`, you aren't going to display `"it is most likely Invalid"`, so it's better to throw an exception from the method, catch it on the caller side and show an error message window:

```
class Seasons {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String response = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the temperature");
        int inputTemp = Integer.parseInt(response);
        try {
            String message = String.format("Based on the temperature of %d, it is most likely %s", inputTemp, determineSeason(inputTemp));
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
        } catch (IllegalTemperatureValueException | NumberFormatException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }

    }

    private static String determineSeason(int inputTemp) throws IllegalTemperatureValueException {
        if (inputTemp > 130 || inputTemp < -20) {
            throw new IllegalTemperatureValueException("incorrect temperature value");
        }

        return inputTemp >= 90 ? "summer" : (inputTemp >= 70 ? "spring" : "winter");
    }
}

class IllegalTemperatureValueException extends Exception {
    public IllegalTemperatureValueException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: @BackwaterStank I did a little refactoring, added a custom exception and displaying an error window. Have a look, please.

Answer (score 1):

You don't assign a result to `season` and you just return `null`.

Change each conditional inside of your if statement to something along the lines of this.

```
String season = null;
if (inputTemp > 130 || inputTemp < -20) {
    season = "invalid";
} else if(inputTemp >= 90) {
    season = "summer";
}
```

Comment: Now I understand! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use interfaces and java 8 Streams. That way you avoid a lot of ifs, which makes the code less verbose, and the introduction of a new class becomes trivial.

Even in small or simple projects, consider interface-oriented programming, which makes you think more before declaring a new method.

#### Season.java

```
public abstract class Season {

    public <T extends Season> Stream season(Integer temperature) {
        if (temperature <= max() && temperature >= min()) {
            return Stream.of(this);
        }
        return Stream.empty();
    }

    public abstract Integer max();

    public abstract Integer min();

    @Override
    public abstract String toString();
}
```

#### Summer.java

```
public class Summer extends Season {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Summer";
    }

    @Override
    public Integer max() {
        return 90;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer min() {
        return 70;
    }
}
```

#### Spring.java

```
public class Spring extends Season {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Spring";
    }

    @Override
    public Integer max() {
        return 69;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer min() {
        return 40;
    }
}
```

#### Main.java

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Collection<Season> seasons = new ArrayList();
        seasons.add(new Summer());
        seasons.add(new Winter());
        seasons.add(new Season() {
            @Override
            public Integer max() {
                return 39;
            }

            @Override
            public Integer min() {
                return 10;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "Winter";
            }
        });

        String response = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the temperature");
        int temperature = Integer.parseInt(response);
        String msg = "Based on the temperature of %d it is most likely %s%n";

        seasons.stream().forEach(s -> {
            s.season(temperature).findAny().ifPresent(t -> {
                String message = String.format(msg, temperature, t);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
            });
        });
    }
}
```